# Converting circular structure to JSON starting at object with constructor 'Subscriber'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, circular-reference

I'm getting the following error when trying to subscribe to my observable.  I'm not quite certain why because I'm not using any type of Stringify (to my knowledge) in the code.  It's just getting a JSON array from an api.

```
 ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
        --> starting at object with constructor 'Subscriber'
        |     property '_subscriptions' -> object with constructor 'Array'
        |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'MapSubscriber'
        --- property '_parentOrParents' closes the circle
        at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
        at JsonPipe.transform (common.js:4752)
        at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (core.js:25782)
        at TicketlistComponent_Template (ticketlist.component.html:4)
        at executeTemplate (core.js:9600)
        at refreshView (core.js:9466)
        at refreshComponent (core.js:10637)
        at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9263)
        at refreshView (core.js:9516)
        at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10591)
```

It seems to occur right after the observable is returned from the Service

AppModule

```
import { NgModule, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatMenuModule, MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { NgbNavModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { TicketlistComponent } from './ticketlist/ticketlist.component';
import { TicketdetailComponent } from './ticketdetail/ticketdetail.component';
import { TicketcenterComponent } from './ticketcenter/ticketcenter.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent, 
    HomeComponent, TicketlistComponent, TicketdetailComponent, TicketcenterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    BrowserAnimationsModule, 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    MatMenuModule, 
    MatButtonModule, 
    MatDividerModule, 
    NgbNavModule, 
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

 }
```

AppComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from '../app/home/home.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Charity';

  ngOnInit(home = HomeComponent){
    
  }
  
}
```

App-Routing-Module

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TicketlistComponent } from './ticketlist/ticketlist.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "ticketList", component: TicketlistComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

connections service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ITicketList } from '../interfaces/i-ticket-list';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConnectionsService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  myServer: string = "https://localhost:5001/"

  getTicketList(): Observable<ITicketList[]>
  {
    console.log('getTicketList()')
    return this.http.get<ITicketList[]>(this.myServer + "Tickets/getTickets")
  } 
}
```

ticketlist component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ITicketList } from '../interfaces/i-ticket-list';
import { ConnectionsService } from '../services/connections.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ticketlist',
  templateUrl: './ticketlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ticketlist.component.scss']
})
export class TicketlistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private connService : ConnectionsService) { }

  getTickets$ : Observable<ITicketList[]> | any;

  getTickets()
  {
    console.log('getTickets')
    this.getTickets$ = this.connService.getTicketList().subscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log('ngOnInit')
    this.getTickets();

  }

}
```

ticketlist html

```
<p>ticketlist works!</p>

<!-- <div *ngIf="getTickets$ | async as getTickets; else loading"> -->
    {{ getTickets$ | json }}
<!-- </div> -->

<!-- <ng-template #loading>
    loading...
</ng-template> -->
```

ITicketList (Interface)

```
export interface ITicketList {

    ticketId : string, 
    customerId: string, 
    createdOn: Date, 
    statusId: number, 
    statusDesc: string

}
```

Sample Payload

```
[{"ticketId":"b4d8e061-1bd9-eb11-8f59-9408532f1cc6","customerId":"b3d8e061-1bd9-eb11-8f59-9408532f1cc6","createdOn":"2021-06-29T16:48:40.44","statusId":1,"statusDesc":"Open"}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From reading the error call stack, I think it's this line:

```
{{ getTickets$ | json }}
```

You can't `json` pipe an Observable stream.

It should instead be something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="getTickets$ | async as getTickets; else loading">
    {{ getTickets | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: Well...  yes and no...  it resolved that error but now I'm getting the error

ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4212)
    at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:4314)
    at AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:4304)
    at AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:4292)

Comment: at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (core.js:25782)
    at TicketlistComponent_Template (ticketlist.component.html:3)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:9600)
    at refreshView (core.js:9466)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10637)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9263)

suggestions?  (or should I post it in another post?)

Comment: So it looks like the problem is the word "Subscribe()".  It works fine without it.  But it's odd.  I thought Observables needed to be Subscribed to

Comment: The async pipe *automatically * subscribes and unsubscribes for you. That's one of its benefits.

Comment: Check out this youtube video for more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=869&v=7AvI6F8ifqU (the relevant part is 45 minutes)